# ZSH, complete to longest prefix

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I no longer find the combination of settings in ZSH that first completes to the longest prefix. What I'm looking for is this:

Given several files aaa, aab, cab, if you type a + tab, ZSH completes to aa, then starts to cycle through aaa and aab.